# Remove CTRL+F5 hotkey Debian

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, hotkeys

I have recently installed Debian-Bullseye into Virtual Box. Programming in VSCode there are typically two hotkeys that help the programming. <kbd>F5</kbd> starts the Debugger, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> runs the project.

Programming in other operation systems I am used to use these hotkeys. However, in this instance of the virtual machine <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> throws me out from the GUI into the terminal login screen. I log in and cannot restore the GUI session where all my applications and VSCode are open.

Is it possible to remove this key binding from this instance of the virtual machine?
Is it possible to restore the graphical session, even if I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> again automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/179707/963426)
from the post
[Why doesn't Ctrl + F5 work in Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48475/why-doesnt-ctrl-f5-work-in-firefox)

> This problem occurs because Xubuntu uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
> to switch into fifth workspace (if you don't have as much workspaces,
> then simply nothing happens), in fact whole
> <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> range is reserved.
>
> There are two possible solutions:
>
> - Redefine (clear) shorcut in Xubuntu (via Settings→Settings Manager→Window Manager→Keyboard) or
> - Use alternative i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

(the second above solution doesn't apply to your case.)